# Not able to export my model for deployment On Azure Custom Vision

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the compact domain to train my Object detection model but still, I am not able to export my model for deployment.

How do I able to export it.
If somebody knows please help me out with this.
[This is my subscription type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVwK0.png)

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-your-model#export-your-model

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but it isn't working for my account.

Comment: is there any other way ?

Comment: Can you please share project settings, also screenshot of the the iteration that you are trying to export.

Answer (score 1):

In your project, you will see at the top the following links:
**Training Images, Performance, Predictions, Train** and **Quick Test**.

1. Click on the settings icon next to the last link and select a compact domain such as **General(compact)**.
2. Click Train to retrain the model on the new compact domain

Then, under the performance menu, you will be able to export your model.

[Use this link for a detailed guide with screenshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-your-model#convert-to-a-compact-domain)

Answer (score 0):

We are able to export the trained custom vision object detection model as shown below. Select the desired export format, and then select Export to download the model.
[image]